# Android Studio Error | Emulator: emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:496: Failed to create Vulkan instance

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation

As the title shows I have an issue with Android Studio on my Linux Mint 19.3. I've tried to install Android Studio via the official download page, the Software Manager and now latest via snap. The failed to create vulkan instance is the first error of many when I try to launch an app in android studio 3.6.1. The emulator screen is black and nothing happens.

System setup

- Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia, based on Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
- Kernel: 5.3.0-40-generic x86_64
- Dell XPS 13 9343

I have all drivers installed.

This is the event log when I try to launch my app:

```
17.3.2020
10:32   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /home/samuel/Downloads/Exemple2
10:32   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:496: Failed to create Vulkan instance.
10:32   Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile: /home/samuel/.android/emulator-grpc.cer security will be disabled.
10:32   Emulator: E0317 10:32:43.165019034   12845 socket_utils_common_posix.cc:201] check for SO_REUSEPORT: {"created":"@1584433963.164985521","description":"SO_REUSEPORT unavailable on compiling system","file":"/mnt/tmpfs/src/android/emu-master-dev/external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":169}
10:32   Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554
10:32   Gradle build finished in 1 s 288 ms
```

Comment: wiping the data of the emulator worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

For me with just basic Celeron Intel onboard graphics I did:

```
sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers
```

Then I got an error about Vulkan 1.1 API not being found, so I [added an updated repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59799821):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
sudo apt update # may be automatic when adding repo
sudo apt upgrade
```

I then continued getting the 1.1 API error, and [downgraded my emulator to version 28](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57797614), and that fixed the Vulkan issues.

Turns out my Celeron is incredibly bad at emulating, but at least now it runs without freezing the system completely. Maybe it will be better with a proper video card, when I might use [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/install-and-test-vulkan-on-linux) for getting the right drivers. :)

Answer (score -1):

Created a new device and it was fixed.

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to explain what you did in a little more detail? As it stands, it’s unlikely to be useful to anyone else.

Comment: For me, I created a new virtual device in the AVD Manager and the problem was resolved.